# Trouble obtaining counts using multiple datetime columns as conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to collect counts of occurrences of an id between two time periods in a dataframe. I have a moderately sized dataframe (about 400 unique ids and just short of 1m rows) containing a time of occurrence and an id for the account which caused the occurrence. I am attempting to get a count of occurrences for multiple time periods (1 hour, 6 hour, 1 day, etc.) prior a specific occurrence and have run into lots of difficulties.

I am using Python 3.7, and for this instance I only have the pandas package loaded. I have tried using for loops and while it likely would have worked (eventually), I am looking for something a bit more efficient time-wise. I have also tried using list comprehension and have run into some errors that I did not anticipate when dealing with datetimes columns. Examples of both are below.

```py
## Sample data
data = {'id':[  'EAED813857474821E1A61F588FABA345', 'D528C270B80F11E284931A7D66640965', '6F394474B8C511E2A76C1A7D66640965', '7B9C7C02F19711E38C670EDFB82A24A9', '80B409D1EC3D4CC483239D15AAE39F2E', '314EB192F25F11E3B68A0EDFB82A24A9', '68D30EE473FE11E49C060EDFB82A24A9', '156097CF030E4519DBDF84419B855E10', 'EE80E4C0B82B11E28C561A7D66640965', 'CA9F2DF6B82011E28C561A7D66640965', '6F394474B8C511E2A76C1A7D66640965', '314EB192F25F11E3B68A0EDFB82A24A9', 'D528C270B80F11E284931A7D66640965', '3A024345C1E94CED8C7E0DA3A96BBDCA', '314EB192F25F11E3B68A0EDFB82A24A9', '47C18B6B38E540508561A9DD52FD0B79', 'B72F6EA5565B49BBEDE0E66B737A8E6B', '47C18B6B38E540508561A9DD52FD0B79', 'B92CB51EFA2611E2AEEF1A7D66640965', '136EDF0536F644E0ADE6F25BB293DD17', '7B9C7C02F19711E38C670EDFB82A24A9', 'C5FAF9ACB88D4B55AB8196DBFFE5B3C0', '1557D4ECEFA74B40C718A4E5425F3ACB', '68D30EE473FE11E49C060EDFB82A24A9', '68D30EE473FE11E49C060EDFB82A24A9', 'CAF9D8CD627B422DFE1D587D25FC4035', 'C620D865AEE1412E9F3CA64CB86DC484', '47C18B6B38E540508561A9DD52FD0B79', 'CA9F2DF6B82011E28C561A7D66640965', '06E2501CB81811E290EF1A7D66640965', '68EEE17873FE11E4B5B90AFEF9534BE1', '47C18B6B38E540508561A9DD52FD0B79', '1BFE9CB25AD84B64CC2D04EF94237749', '7B20C2BEB82811E28C561A7D66640965', '261692EA8EE447AEF3804836E4404620', '74D7C3901F234993B4788EFA9E6BEE9E', 'CAF9D8CD627B422DFE1D587D25FC4035', '76AAF82EB8C511E2A76C1A7D66640965', '4BD38D6D44084681AFE13C146542A565', 'B8D27E80B82911E28C561A7D66640965'  ], 'datetime':[ "24/06/2018 19:56", "24/05/2018 03:45", "12/01/2019 14:36", "18/08/2018 22:42", "19/11/2018 15:43", "08/07/2017 21:32", "15/05/2017 14:00", "25/03/2019 22:12", "27/02/2018 01:59", "26/05/2019 21:50", "11/02/2017 01:33", "19/11/2017 19:17", "04/04/2019 13:46", "08/05/2019 14:12", "11/02/2018 02:00", "07/04/2018 16:15", "29/10/2016 20:17", "17/11/2018 21:58", "12/05/2017 16:39", "28/01/2016 19:00", "24/02/2019 19:55", "13/06/2019 19:24", "30/09/2016 18:02", "14/07/2018 17:59", "06/04/2018 22:19", "25/08/2017 17:51", "07/04/2019 02:24", "26/05/2018 17:41", "27/08/2014 06:45", "15/07/2016 19:30", "30/10/2016 20:08", "15/09/2018 18:45", "29/01/2018 02:13", "10/09/2014 23:10", "11/05/2017 22:00", "31/05/2019 23:58", "19/02/2019 02:34", "02/02/2019 01:02", "27/04/2018 04:00", "29/11/2017 20:35"]}
df = pd.dataframe(data)

df = df.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'], ascending=True)
# for loop attempt
totalAccounts = df['id'].unique()
for account in totalAccounts:
     oneHourCount=0
     subset = df[df['id'] == account]
     for i in range(len(subset)):
          onehour = subset['datetime'].iloc[i] - timedelta(hours=1)
          for j in range(len(subset)):

                    if (subset['datetime'].iloc[j] >= onehour) and (subset['datetime'].iloc[j] < sub):
                        oneHourCount+=1


#list comprehension attempt
df['onehour'] = df['datetime'] - timedelta(hours=1)
for account in totalAccounts:
     onehour = sum([1 for x in subset['datetime'] if x >= subset['onehour'] and x < subset['datetime']])
```

I am getting either 1) incredibly long runtime with the for loop or 2) an ValueError  regarding the truth of a series being ambiguous. I know the issue is dealing with the datetimes, and perhaps it is just going to be slow-going, but I want to check here first just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out using bisection. If you have a similar question please PM me and I'd be more than happy to help.

Solution:

```
left = bisect_left(keys, subset['start_time'].iloc[i]) ## calculated time
right = bisect_right(keys, subset['datetime'].iloc[i]) ## actual time of occurrence

count=len(subset['datetime'][left:right]
```